# Published on Play Store but app doesn't open

Tags: crash, google-play, google-play-services

I have recently uploaded my app onto Google play store and it got published which was very exciting for me, but now when I try to open it on an android device it doesn't open as shown in the picture. Is there a reason for this?

[image: Alert on google playstore app stopping]

Answer (score 0):

Your game has fatal exception, try to find the way to fix it

[image: this is logs]

[image]

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: I downloaded your game from Play Marker and tried to open it

Comment: have you activated developer mode on your phone? try to play your game with Unity, if you develop on it

Comment: I do not have an android phone. I developed on unity and it works but then I used android studio to add a 64 bit library because google play didn't allow 34 bit. I try to build 64 bit on unity but it does not allow me.

Comment: Are you aware of the Building native library IL2CPP error?

Comment: If you dont have an android, you can use emulator to test your games. I atteched my configurations, my app works well

Comment: I try that but as I said it fails to build the IL2CPP. What unity version are you using?

Comment: i use 2019.3.6f1

Comment: I try to download it and then when I change the version of my project it doesn't change over. I feel like if I am able to do that then it will work!

Comment: It should works, maybe you didn't switch the version of your project?

Comment: i download it on unity hub, select my project version drop down menu, change version, click confirm to changing the data and then it does nothing.

Comment: oh, sorry, but i dont know what actually the problem can be, try to google or create new project with new version

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The problem was that my macbook was not allowing clang++ from opening during the building of the IL2CPP. I then opened terminal and implemented this line of code to disable the security control:

```
sudo spctl –-master-disable
```

Put in my password and allowed for my mac to open the ndk stuff and I was able to successfully played my game on playstore :).

check it out if you want!: [my first game!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.GuzGamez.Gravitoss)